# Animating dashstyle in YUI graphics

Tags: graphics, line, yui

### Animated Dashed Lines

Using YUI, I would like to draw lines that are dashed.  The curve ball is that I would like to animate the dashstyle to change from one size of dash to another and back again every 2 seconds or so, say from:

```
dashstyle: [10,10]
```

to

```
dashstyle: [10,20]
```

The purpose is to simulate fluid flowing in pipe-work, so the lines will bend around the pipe work simulating where fluid is flowing.

Can this be animated easily in YUI? I've tried myself, but couldn't get the dashstyle to animate.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to switch between the two, you can use Y.later() to create a timer which toggles a CSS class.

Animation is more useful for smooth changes.  You can create custom plug ins for the animation module.  For example:

http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/boxshadow-anim

http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/textshadow-anim

Comment: Can you change an SVN graphics line type with CSS? I'm using the YUI Grapics modules.

Comment: I don't think the Graphics module exposes it directly.  It sounds like you're using the stroke attribute, and that is certainly CSS-like, but the Animation module only works directly on CSS attributes.  One would have to tweak the Animation code to work on CSS-like attributes.